# GWT dynamically re-sizable header

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

Working on a program that displays data in datagrid.  Successfully created Excel-like drag-and-drop re-sizable headers. Program also contains options to add or remove columns from a list.  The problem is as follows:

Resized columns shrink in width when a new column is added or removed.  The bug is almost definitely coming from the class where the headers were created. When there are only a few columns in the grid, the draggable area (where cursor icon changes to the col-resize cursor) is offset to the left from the exact midpoint between columns by anywhere between 15-20px.  As number of columns increases, this offset shrinks steadily until the drag icon appears right over the midpoint between columns, where it should be.

I am storing and maintaining all column widths with a map, and where the draggable area is offset, the column widths are mis-measured in the map (e.g. a column with a measured width of 100px might be put into the map as 70px, which is how it will render on add/remove column). This does not happen where the offset is nil, so the offset is likely the cause of my woes.

When I try to move the location of the draggable area by subtracting "offset-left" from the place I set its location, nothing happens.

Looking for a suggestion as to how to adjust the location of my draggable area.  Code below:

```
public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event)
    {
        NativeEvent nativeEvent = event.getNativeEvent();
        nativeEvent.preventDefault();
        nativeEvent.stopPropagation();

        String eventType = nativeEvent.getType();
        int clientX = nativeEvent.getClientX();
        if (eventType.equals("mousemove") && this.mousedown)
        {
            int absoluteLeft = this.el.getAbsoluteLeft();
            int offsetLeft = this.el.getOffsetLeft();
            int newWidth = clientX - absoluteLeft;
            newWidth = newWidth < width ? width : newWidth;
            this.table.setColumnWidth(this.col, newWidth + "px");
            return;
        }

        if (eventType.equals("mousemove") || eventType.equals("mousedown"))
        {
            Element eventTargetEl = nativeEvent.getEventTarget().cast();
            int absoluteLeft = eventTargetEl.getAbsoluteLeft();
            int offsetWidth = eventTargetEl.getOffsetWidth();
            // WIDTH of the clickable location is determined ("width" = constant: 20px)
            if (clientX > (absoluteLeft) + offsetWidth - width)
            {
                if (eventType.equals("mousedown"))
                {
                    this.mousedown = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //setting cursor icon to col-resize - this MUST relate to draggable area
                    setCursor(this.el, Cursor.COL_RESIZE);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                removeHandler();
                return;
            }
        }
```